# How disable public access in elasticsearch port 9200

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

I installed elasticsearch server. There is external access to elasticsearch [www.example.com:9200](http://www.example.com:9200) port on this server on Windows server. I want to restrict this. My application that I use Elasticsearch is running on another server.

When a request is sent from the app server, Elasticsearch server searches and sends a request back. There is no problem in its operation, but when [www.example.com:9200](http://www.example.com:9200) is connected from any computer (except those with server access), port 9200 can be accessed.

What should I do to keep it open only for app server access?

I don't want to change it with firewall, I had a few problems with firewall during installation.
Thanks. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable the [CORS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/current/analytics-cors-proxy.html) and set the `http.cors.allow-origin` to allow access for some specific IP's to Elasticsearch.

*Note: CORS is disabled by default.*

Update elasticsearch.yml with the following credentials.

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "*" # Only use unrestricted value for local development
# Use a specific origin value in production, like `http.cors.allow-origin: "https://<my-website-domain.example>"`
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, POST
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Accept
```

Optionally, you can set multiple allowed origins using a comma-separated list:

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "http://domain1:port, http://domain2:port"
```

Don't forget to restart the elasticsearch.yml after update the yaml.

> Setting the http.cors.allow-origin will restrict access to elasticsearch:port on the browser as you want.

> However, please note that the http.cors.allow-origin setting alone
> won't provide full access control or restrict access to specific IP
> addresses. CORS is primarily used to manage requests from web browsers
> in web applications and does not provide the same level of security as
> firewall rules or network configurations.

Comment: Rica ederim Yunus, happy to hear it worked :)